# What is next in information technology industry?

Tags: career-development, job-change, technology

I am an IT professional with 10 years of experience, I started with my career with production support analyst, I did it for two years. Then I switched job and became a Java/Perl developer for two years. and in my next switch I joined a development team where I worked as perl script developer for 3 years and then since last 3 years I am into People Management, project management and very little bit of coding.
I want to have a change now, what should I do after 10 year of IT experience?

Comment: Do you want to be in management?

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick, it really depends what level you want to change to.

Hardware

Running a business

Sales

Web

Databases

Administration

IT is a huge, ever evolving field, plenty of choices, but only you can choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should leave IT.  Seems you've been in it for the money, but this is not your passion if you've bounced around in IT jobs for ten years and neither know where you're going in it or what the trends are.

Money does not equate to passion, happiness, or being content.